# How do I specify the path of the config class in INSTALLED_APPS in Django?

Tags: django

The following tree, show my Django project structure. Now, in plain English, how do I add a new entry to INSTALLED_APPS in Django setting.py? (have already wasted 6 hours on this :(

```
|   manage.py
|   db.sqlite3
|   
+---journal
|   |   asgi.py
|   |   settings.py
|   |   urls.py
|   |   wsgi.py
|   |   __init__.py
|           
\---apps
    \---cards
        |   admin.py
        |   apps.py
        |   models.py
        |   tests.py
        |   urls.py
        |   views.py
        |   __init__.py
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you only add the name of the app in INSTALLED_APPS.

Example

Your app name is "cards", inside of apps.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'apps.cards',
]
```

Comment: I replaced 'main' with 'cards' (my app's name) in the above code and I got this: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cards'

Comment: Well, sorry, in your case, 'apps.cards'. Prove this. @Joseph_Marzbani

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. I should have modified the config class itslef! Inside `CardsConfig` I had to change the `name` from `Cards` into `'apps.cards'`.